# How to test android widget using robotium

Tags: android, robotium

Android widget contains many icons as buttons.what is the testcode for selecting that icon.

Just like music player widget contains play icon as button.ASAP can any one reply to this...

Thanks

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you want. I believe you mean that you want to implement code in your app that allows a user to select which icon will be shown for your application's widget. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Robotium is unable to test widgets. It can only test code that happens within your application under tests process.